# Swagger UI & Api docs not opening, with Springdoc WebMvc throws UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS Permission error

Tags: openapi, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I've tried opening swagger UI and api docs with the latest dependency of springdoc :

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

The swagger UI and the api docs link at:

localhost:8085/appName/v3/api/docs
localhost:8085/appName/swagger-ui/index.html

while opening throws the error on browser :

```
{
"errorType": "UNAUTHORIZED",
"category": "ACCESS_PERMISSION",
"severity": "BLOCKER",
"errorObject": {
"errorType": "UNAUTHORIZED",
"category": "ACCESS_PERMISSION",
"severity": "BLOCKER",
"time": "Dec 27, 2023, 3:47:00 PM",
"message": "Authentiaction Failure, Login and try again !"
},
"time": "Dec 27, 2023, 3:47:00 PM",
"errCodeMap": {},
"detailMessage": "Authentiaction Failure, Login and try again !",
"stackTrace": \[\],
"suppressedExceptions": \[\]
}
```

The same when tried with springdoc-openapi-ui dependency and @EnablWebMvc was working fine with configured security.
have also included the swagger antmatchers in the websecurity still it shows the auhtorization issue.

Can anyone help or have faced this issue?